# Nginx + uWSGI + Django too slow

Tags: django, performance, nginx, uwsgi

I have django running on nginx and uwsgi. The cached response loads very fast but at other times the website takes more than 30s to load. I am unable to diagnose the root cause of slowing down. Here's what I can provide as info to help narrow down the issue -

1. **GTMetrix** - For what I can conclude from waterfall report is that the waiting time for static files is too much alongwith the initial server response time. Here is a more detailed breakdown:
   [Link to the lighthouse parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JI79j.jpg) [Waterfall report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHYwe.jpg)
2. **nginx.conf** - Here is the nginx config file:

   ```
    user www-data;
    worker_processes 4;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;

    events {
        worker_connections 768;
    }

    http {
        sendfile              on;
        tcp_nopush            on;
        tcp_nodelay           on;
        keepalive_timeout     75;
        types_hash_max_size   2048;
        client_max_body_size  5M;
        sendfile_max_chunk    512;
        include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;



        log_format  upstream_time '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] ' 
                          '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent ' 
                          '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"' 
                          'rt="$request_time" uct="$upstream_connect_time" 
                           uht="$upstream_header_time" urt="$upstream_response_time"';

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  upstream_time;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip  on;
        gzip_disable msie6;
        # And all the gzip mime types here

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
        proxy_cache_path /data/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m max_size=10g
                         inactive 60m use_temp_path off; 

        server {
            location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js){
                proxy_cache             my_cache;
                proxy_cache_revalidate  on;
                proxy_cache_min_uses    3;
                proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 
                                                             http_504;
                proxy_cache_lock        on;
                expires                 365d;
                proxy_pass              http://example.net;
            }
        }
    }
   ```
3. **Nginx Project Config** -

   ```
        map $sent_http_content_type $expires{
            default                     on;
            text/html                   epoch;
            text/css                    max;
            appplication/javascript     max;
            ~image/                     max;       
        }

        server{

        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        location /static/ {
            root /home/mysite/project_dir/app_dir;
            expires  $expires;
        }
        location /images/ {
            expires  $expires;
            root /home/mysite/project_dir/app_dir/static/images/;
        }
        location /media/ {
            expires  $expires;
            root /home/mysite/project_dir/;
        }

        location / {
            include                  uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass               unix:/run/uwsgi/mysite.sock;
            gzip_static              on;
            proxy_buffering          off;
            proxy_cache              my_cache;
            proxy_cache_revalidate   on;
            proxy_cache_min_uses     3;
            proxy_cache_use_stale    error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 
                                                             http_504;
            proxy_cache_lock         on;
            expires                  365d;
            proxy_set_header         X-Real-IP  $remote-addr;
            proxy_set_header         Host       $http-host;
            proxy_set_header         Connection "";
        }

        listen 443 ssl http2;#Managed by certbot
        #All the subsequent certbot settings not tampered with
    }
   ```
4. **Logs** - So, when I log nginx using the above config, the access logs show *upstream_response_time* perfectly only if the website was cached loaded. When it takes >30s to load, the *upstream_response_time* including all parameters except response_time show hyphen '-'.

**UPDATE:**

6. **django-debug-toolbar**- Resource Usage:

| Resource | Value |
| --- | --- |
| User CPU time | 964.000 msec |
| System CPU time | 52.000 msec |
| Total CPU time | 1016.000 msec |
| System CPU time | 1019.185 msec |

All the SQL queries are taking minimal time(10.78ms). Logger too shows 0 errors.

I would highly appreciate if anyone could help me diagnose the root cause of this slowdown. Thank you!

Comment: you can debug where it is taking time by using https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thank you! I will update after using the toolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phew! So I figured out the solution. I used - https://www.webpagetest.org and arrived to a conclusion that the initial connection time was very high (~30s). When it happens, it is most likely some dns/firewall issue. My issue was dns based. I had 2 ips added as A record to my domain. One was a private ip. So the browser actually took ~30s to load that ip and when the website got loaded, the browser cached the response so the subsequent response times were low. Simply removing the private ip worked for me.